# :onchange in form not working, in rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is exactly my problem. In my case the :onchange function is not working, though I have added the jquery in the application.rb.

in the form, I need to alert the users

```
<%= telephone_field(:user, :phone_country_code, :size => 1, :onchange => "if $('user[phone_country_code]').length > 2 { alert('Your firstname needs to be shorter!'); }") %>
```

in application.html.rb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
```

in the console I am getting

```
Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-27 12:36:39 +0530
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
```

Comment: @mu, could you also edit the table (.onchnage vs .onchange)

Comment: @rdvdijk: You mean the title? I'll have you know that I had to correct two of my own typos while entering the log message for my last "typo in the title" edit :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax error in your javascript. Add parentheses:

```
if ($('user[phone_country_code]').length > 2) { alert('Your firstname needs to be shorter!'); }")
```

Also: strange alert for a country code..